# TextView is not showing full text in 1 line - Android

Tags: android, textview

I create a `TextView` programmatically. I set up the marquee and single line as this:

```
contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setSingleLine(true);
contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setMaxLines(1);
contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setLines(1);
contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1); // marquee forever
contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setFocusable(true);
contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setSelected(true);
```

Still i see text only on the same width as the screen, the other text is not shown. As i try to slide the `TextView` from left to right.

I tried to set the width to a very large width, it still not working.

any suggestions on how to let the `TextView` show the full text in 1 line ??

Comment: Are u using on textView matchParent width?

Comment: @Rodriquez no i use setWidth(3000) and i tried many other bigger values, still same result

Comment: wrap_content? try it this must work like how many text == so many size

Comment: Call `MATCH_PARENT` .Avoid to use hardcoded `3000`

Comment: What about `WRAP_CONTENT` ?

Answer (score 1):

I am trying your code and i am getting like that and I am add the params

> Code

```
 LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);



    contol_list_textview_scrolltext=new TextView[7];
    for (int t=0;t<7;t++)
    {

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t]=new TextView(demo.this);
        contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setSingleLine(true);
        contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setMaxLines(1);
        contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setLines(1);
        contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1); // marquee forever
        contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
        contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
        contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setFocusable(true);
        contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setSelected(true);
        contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setLayoutParams(params);
        contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setTextSize(30);
        contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t].setText("I am fan of Stackoverflow website. It so helping to me also to other. Tons of example here to solve us problem and also we ask question solve in a minuts or good helping ");
        linearLayout.addView(contol_list_textview_scrolltext[t]);
    }
```

> xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

> Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> As i try to slide the TextView from left to right.

`TextView` will not scroll without. You have to add it in a parent that have scroll behavior, like [HorizontalScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html).

Comment: sliding it with animation, so no need to parent

Answer (score 0):

`WRAP_CONTENT` should do it.

> One more thing

Try the necessary attributes first like `.setSingleLine(true),setHorizontallyScrolling(true);setellipsize(textutils.truncateat.MARQUEE)`